# network is not available even when cisco vpn client is connected. wrong route?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn, 3g

I'm using Vodafone 3G modem. I've disabled other network devices in the system (ethernet, wifi, wimax) turned off firewall and antivirus.
cisco vpn client connects successfully but I still can not access computer 192.168.147.120 (as well as any other computer from network).

Any suggestions are welcome as I don't know what to do.

`ipconfig /all` and `route print` commands (translated to english):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(C) Microsoft Corporation (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. All rights reserved.

C: \ Users \ Oleg> ipconfig / all

IP Configuration for Windows

   The name of the computer. . . . . . . . . : OlegPC
   The primary DNS-suffix. . . . . . :
   Node Type. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-routing is enabled. . . . : No
   WINS-proxy enabled. . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco Systems VPN Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . 00-05-9A-3C-78-00
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes
   Local IPv6-address channel. . . : Fe80:: c073: 41b2: 852f: eb87% 26 (Preferred)
   IPv4-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.53.127.204 (Preferred)
   The subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . . : 536872346
   DUID the client DHCPv6. . . . . . . 00-01-00-01-14-6F-4C-8D-60-EB-69-85-10-2D

   DNS-servers. . . . . . . . . . . : Fec0: 0:0: ffff:: 1% 1
                                       fec0: 0:0: ffff:: 2% 1
                                       fec0: 0:0: ffff:: 3% 1
   NetBios over TCP / IP. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Adapter mobile broadband connection through a broadband adapter
mobile communications:

   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Vodafone Mobile Broadband Network Adapter
 (Huawei)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . 58-2C-80-13-92-63
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes
   IPv4-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.229.227.77 (Preferred)
   The subnet mask. . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . : 10.229.227.78
   DNS-servers. . . . . . . . . . . : 163.121.128.134
                                       212.103.160.18
   NetBios over TCP / IP. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap. {737FF02E-D473-4F91-840E-2A4DD293FC12}:

   State of the environment. . . . . . . . : DNS Suffix.
   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Adapter Microsoft ISATAP # 3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap. {EF585226-5B07-4446-A5A4-CB1B8E4B13AC}:

   State of the environment. . . . . . . . : DNS Suffix.
   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Adapter Microsoft ISATAP # 4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   DNS-suffix for this connection. . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . : Yes
   IPv6-address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9 e76: ea: b77: f51a: 1cb2 (Basically
d)
   Local IPv6-address channel. . . : Fe80:: ea: b77: f51a: 1cb2% 16 (Preferred)
   Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . :::
   NetBios over TCP / IP. . . . . . . . : Disabled

C: \ Users \ Oleg> route print
================================================== =========================
List of interfaces
 26 ... 00 05 9a 3c 78 00 ...... Cisco Systems VPN Adapter
 23 ... 58 2c 80 13 92 63 ...... Vodafone Mobile Broadband Network Adapter (Huawei)

  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 19 ... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Adapter Microsoft ISATAP # 3
 20 ... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Adapter Microsoft ISATAP # 4
 16 ... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
================================================== =========================

IPv4 Route Table
================================================== =========================
Active Routes:
Network Destination Netmask Gateway Interface Metric
          0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.229.227.78 10.229.227.77 296
         10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 10.53.127.204 286
       10.6.93.21 255,255,255,255 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
      10.13.50.12 255,255,255,255 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
        10.53.8.0 255.255.252.0 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
    10.53.127.204 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.53.127.204 286
      10.53.128.0 255.255.248.0 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
      10.53.148.0 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
     10.53.148.16 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
    10.229.227.76 255.255.255.252 On-link 10.229.227.77 296
    10.229.227.77 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.229.227.77 296
    10.229.227.79 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.229.227.77 296
   10.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.53.127.204 286
        127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
        127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
  127.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
    192.168.147.0 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
   192.168.147.96 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
  192,168,147,112 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
  192,168,147,128 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
  192,168,147,144 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
  192,168,147,224 255,255,255,240 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
    192.168.214.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
    192.168.215.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
   194.247.133.19 255,255,255,255 10.0.0.1 10.53.127.204 100
  213,247,231,194 255,255,255,255 10.229.227.78 10.229.227.77 100
        224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
        224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 10.229.227.77 296
        224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 On-link 10.53.127.204 286
  255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 127.0.0.1 306
  255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.229.227.77 296
  255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 On-link 10.53.127.204 286
================================================== =========================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
================================================== =========================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination Gateway
 16 58:: / 0 On-link
  1306:: 1 / 128 On-link
 16 58 2001:: / 32 On-link
 16 306 2001: 0:4137:9 e76: ea: b77: f51a: 1cb2/128
                                    On-link
 16 306 fe80:: / 64 On-link
 26 286 fe80:: / 64 On-link
 16 306 fe80:: ea: b77: f51a: 1cb2/128
                                    On-link
 26 286 fe80:: c073: 41b2: 852f: eb87/128
                                    On-link
  1306 ff00:: / 8 On-link
 16 306 ff00:: / 8 On-link
 26 286 ff00:: / 8 On-link
================================================== =========================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C: \ Users \ Oleg>
```

Comment: Some of those routes show commas instead of dots, did serverfault format the output incorrectly?

Comment: @Tim yes of course there are dots in the system. this is either google translate or serverfault issue.

Comment: This troubleshooting needs to happen on the VPN device that you're connecting to.  Do you have control of that device?  All the /28 routes for the 192.168.147 range seem a little... creative.

Comment: @ShaneMadden i can contact admins about that, but what do you think would be better instead of that?

Comment: @javapowered You should just contact them about the connectivity issues.  Given how the Cisco VPN software works, the routes are very unlikely to be the issue; it's more likely a broken NAT or ACL config.  The troubleshooting needs to be done from the Cisco device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cisco VPN Adaptor has a subnet mask of 255.0.0.0 and ip 10.53.127.204 and the 3G dongle has subnet mask of 255.255.255.252 and ip address of 10.229.227.77.

There is some overlap between these two subnets which might be confusing windows.

If say for instance, all the devices you need to access over the vpn are 10.53.127.x addresses, then consider changing the mask for the vpn to 255.255.255.0, if you need access to 10.53.x.x over vpn, you could change the mask 255.255.0.0.

To be honest I'm not certain if this actually is the issue, but overlapping subnets isn't going to help anything. If you are not certain of the correct subnet it may be an idea to speak to your network admin.

Edit: Also noticed no default gateway for your vpn.

Also as mentioned the routes for the 192.168.x.x addresses do look a little odd, although I do remember manually setting up routes where the specified gateway was actually the ip of my end of the VPN for various quick checks on stuff. If you are using win7, it could be worth trying to change these routes so the gateway actaully is the device at the other end but if I recall correctly that didn't work right with XP.

Edit 2: The ip address for the VPN says (preferred) at the end, while DHCP is off. That doesn't quite look right to me either.